# Unterschied zwischen Entscheidung und Entschluss

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between *Entscheidung* and *Entschluss*? In my mother tongue they both represent the English word *decision*.

Comment: Welcome to german.SE :) Did you use a dictionary? Can you explain why it did not help?

Comment: @choXer Sure. I looked up and most dictionaries just top the translation "decision" https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/entscheidung https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/entschluss Based on the examples, I have no clue what the difference is.

Comment: The English Wiktionary lists "decision" as a possible translation for both words, but they're different meanings of the word. A "decision" (*Entscheidung*) is a choice between alternatives. With "decision"(*Entschluss*) means with finality, and certainty.

Comment: @RDBury finally someone put it understandable. Thank you

Comment: Perhaps _den Entschluss fassen, etw zu tun_ = 'to make up one's mind to do sth' versus _eine (endgültige) Entscheidung treffen_ = 'to make a (final) decision' can be helpful. _Sich entscheiden_ is much more a resolution in the mind, whereas _sich entschließen_ means 'to suit the action to the word or thought'. _Ein Entschluss_ is closer to the intended consequences and actions: _Ihre Entscheidung, nicht in Berlin zu bleiben, stand längst fest. Sie hatte den konkreten Entschluss gefasst, noch heute einen Makler aufzusuchen und ein paar alte Freunde aus WG-Zeiten in Freiburg anzurufen._

Answer (score 0):

What is your mother tongue? In English there is a difference.

---

Entschluss:

> He made a **resolution** to get up early.

> Er fasste den **Entschluss**, früh aufzustehen.
> (Er entschloss sich, früh aufzustehen.)

Entscheidung:

> The next morning, he made the **decision** not to do it.

> Am nächsten Morgen, machte er die **Entscheidung** es nicht zu tun. (Am nächsten Morgen, entschied er es nicht zu tun.

---

Comment: Mir wird der Unterschied nicht klar.

Comment: @CarstenS Ein Entschluss ist nicht unbedingt eine Entscheidung. Ich kann mich entschließen etwas zu tun, aber schlussendlich eine andere Entscheidung treffen. Eine Entscheidung ist sozsagen "finaler"..